# Eliminating sliver polygons automatically

Tags: polygon, topology, slivers

I have thousands of sliver polygons outside of my study area. What is the best way to eliminate them automatically? In ArcGIS or QGIS.
Those polygon islands are an example of the slivers.
Note: I can´t select by attributes (small areas) because then it would eliminate other polygons inside the study area.

[image]

Comment: Select by area ?

Comment: Unfortunately not possible because some areas inside my study area are also smaller as some of those slivers

Comment: In ArcMap, can you:
(1) select your study area
(2) spatially select all polygons within your study area (ensuring that your study area and all polygons within it are selected)
(3) 'switch selection' (this will be all areas NOT within your study area) & delete?

Comment: *** Also: not to get caught  up in semantics, but it has been my experience that most GIS practitioners would not refer to these small island polygon features as 'sliver polygons'. The term is typically used in reference to very long/narrow 'slivers' (not usually representing actual geographic features) that erroneously result from close-but-not-quite-coincident polygon boundary lines.

Comment: If you convert Multipart to Singlepart, then you can select all islands, delete, and Dissolve back. You can also review Eliminate.  But first you should choose either QGIS or ArcGIS for your Question, since the answers to the two questions are different

Comment: In QGIS: Judging by your drawing I tried to go in this direction: 1) Create an external one-way buffer that would include all outer islands; 2) Then cut out all outer islands from the buffer; 3) The difference between the original polygon and the outer islands and all...

Comment: Maybe a bit of a frame challenge: if these are outside your study area, why not just ignore them and move on, or simply clip to your study area?

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to the "[Check Geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html)" tool under the Vector menu in QGIS.

[image]